# Incorrect AVA Format : BlackBerry WebWorks SDK

Tags: java, blackberry, keytool, jar-signing

I am trying to sign my webworks application in SDK 2.0.4 and following steps from http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/27280/Configure_signing_for_tablet_applications_1476061_11.jsp.

When i execute following command

```
blackberry-keytool -genkeypair -keystore -torepass xxxxx -dname "My Company Name" -alias author
```

I get the following error

```
keytool error : java.io.IOExceotion: Incorrect AVA format
```

as you can see in the screenshot [image]

I have no idea what does it means, it would be nice if someone can help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [keytool error :java.io.IoException:Incorrect AVA format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808391/keytool-error-java-io-ioexceptionincorrect-ava-format)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your dname is mis-formatted. It should be -dname="cn=xxxxxxxxxx" where xxxxxxxx = the company name you submitted to RIM during the CSJ registration process. I also found out the hard way that there can be no special chars in the company name, or they have to be escaped out (for instance, replace "," with "\2C".