# keytool error :java.io.IoException:Incorrect AVA format

Tags: android, android-keystore

I am new to Android development; when I have been trying to sign the application I have got the following error. Can anyone help me on this issue?

```
keytool error :java.io.IoException:Incorrect AVA format
```

I have found some solution on the forums, for instance I need to run the `debug.keystore` but I was not successful.

Comment: Refer this links ,  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/1J7IFF_jPXQ  ,  http://mortalpowers.com/news/android-development-error-incorrect-ava-format

Comment: And this: http://mortalpowers.com/news/android-development-error-incorrect-ava-format

Comment: Can't google say "Invalid Character".
Instead, they say "Incorret AVA format"
Strip away any non alphanumeric characters, no accents and no weird letters.

Answer (score 555):

Probably you entered illegal character(something like,(comma)) in a field for Name, Organization or somewhere else.

Of course, if you really want some character can be escaped with \ sign

"+" (plus sign) sign also causes this issue. (People often tend to use + sign for the country code field)

Comment: Just FYI, if you really want a comma in a field, you can escape it with a leading backslash, e.g. Acme\, Inc.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html.  This also works in the signing dialog of the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: I found in code the list of characters that must be escaped ,+=<>#;"

Answer (score 54):

I have faced an error while trying to export a signed .apk file with Eclipse ADT. The error was same like your error. In my case, I used a + sign before the country code. By removing the + sign from this name fixed the problem and allowed me to fully export my signed .apk file. 
Also, this error can occur when use comma,slash, semi-colon, quotation.

Comment: Thanks. I used '+' sign too. )

Comment: Thanks. This solved my issue i used + in country code

Answer (score 22):

You tried to use special characters while exporting apk.You can't use these special characters in any field shown while creating the apk. The special character set includes:

- Commas (,)
- Addition symbol (+)
- Quotation mark (")
- Back-slash ("\")
- Angled brackets(< and >)
- Semi-colon (;)

Answer (score 9):

I solved these Exception by changing the country code:

`+91` to 
 `India`

Comment: For this field you should be using the [iso 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) country code, in your case "IN"

Answer (score 8):

Special chars/escaping all good answers/could be the problem; you didn't share your actual "keytool" command line so harder to give an accurate answer.  If you're trying to gen a pub/priv key pair ("-genkeypair" param), then 1 problem would be that the cert subject distinguished name ("**-dname**" arg) wasn't specified in the correct X.500 AVA ("**A**ttribute/**V**alue" **A**ssertion) format.  For example, omitting the "CN=" in front of the subject common name (CN).  Param should look something like this:

```
keytool ... -dname="CN=SomeCertSubject" ...
```

In this distinguished name param, "**CN**" ("Common Name") is the "**A**ttribute", "**SomeCertSubject**" is the "**V**alue".

Comment: not exact but was close enough for me.  i put companyname inc. and the . (dot) of the inc caused a fail.

Answer (score 7):

I came on this error when I did not set the distinguished name option at all. This was corrected by setting the option to a validly formatted string.

this command failed with the AVA format exception: (line breaks added for legibility)

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin>keytool 
-genkey -v -dname PatrickTaylor -validity 10000 
-keystore C:\drops\patrickkeystore
```

this command completed successfully:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin>keytool 
-genkey -v -dname PatrickTaylor -validity 10000 
-keystore C:\drops\patrickkeystore 
-dname "cn=Patrick Taylor, ou=engineering, o=company, c=US"
```

Answer (score 5):

I made a mistake by entering `+` in the front of the country code. so changed the values like below.

`+7` to `7`

it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

this "Probably you entered illegal character(something like ,(comma)) in a field for Name, Organization or somewhere else. " worked for me. I had a comma on the state or province. please mark this answer by rule as the answer; as + in +91 is a special character.

Comment: for me, the error was caused by comma between company name and llc.  (thank you kingsley sithole).

Answer (score 2):

It's a common mistake, when we're going to generate Signed APK in Android Studio. So in **Keystore** file you can't use any special character or symbol such as (**, \  + - * / < > ; ' "**) otherwise, you get java.io.IoException.

See a Demo, how can you fill-up your **Keystore** file:

**Password:** anything without special character or symbol

**Alias:** Key0 (up to you)

**Validity (years):** 25 (up to you)

**First and last Name:** Your proper Name but don't use special character in your name like $unny @dam

**Organizational Unit:** Your organization Name

**Organization:** Your organization Name

**City or Locality:** Your City Name

**State or Province:** Your State or Province Name

**Country Code (XX):** Use your country code, if you don't know then search Google.

**Then click OK**