# After zipalign, I got an eror on keytool

Tags: android, eclipse, keytool, zipalign

I have an application and I wanted to upload it to google play, I got error, so I did the zipalign to it:

> zipalign -v 4 a.apk b.apk

After that, on cmd, I did the keytool to it, I got an error

> keytool error:java.io.IOException: Incorrect AVA format

like oi60.tinypic.com/fw1350.jpg
Can anyone know the problem?

Comment: Use Gradle with Android Studio. Why are you doing this by hand?

Comment: I use eclipse, I have Android Studio and I tried to use it, but there was a problem in it a while ago

Comment: Either way, Eclipse or Android studio, the IDE will do it for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sign an android apk file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file)

Comment: I'd highly suggest switching to Android Studio because Google has ended support for Eclipse.

Comment: I'll see the link you posted, need some time

Comment: Ok, I imported the files to Android Studio, how ca I run it?

Comment: If you are in Eclipse, why didn't you follow the instructions in the link?

Comment: I clicked on run, when it's done, I don't know where it is!

Comment: umm, I'm using Android Studio now :)

Comment: Either way this question is basically a duplicate and has been answered before.

Comment: That line isn't helping, Jared :/

Comment: Few things: 1) You never Googled your issue 2) I helped you by giving you a link for Eclipse 3) I am helping to much and this question should already be closed.

Comment: Google your issues: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19876060/950427

Comment: I got the error again "keytool error:java.io.IOException: Incorrect AVA format"

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808391/keytool-error-java-io-ioexceptionincorrect-ava-format

Comment: It's not duplicate, it worked, it gave me Certificate fingerprints, what shall I do more?

Comment: You exact problem is described in that previous post.